# Debugging in Parts using PyCharm?

Tags: python, debugging, ide, pycharm

Is there a way to debug a piece of code in `PyCharm` in parts. For example in the following code,

```
foo1()
foo2()
foo3()
```

`foo1()` takes a long time to execute. Since I need to debug `foo2()`, I want to start my debugger from `foo2()` but with the results of `foo1()` being available. How can I achieve this? Is there a standard name for this debugging technique?

I recall `MATLAB` having a feature of dividing your scripts into cells which can then be executed and debugged independently. I guess I'm looking for a similar sort of feature in `PyCharm` if it exists.

Comment: Could this question be rewritten into "Could I get the result of a function without executing it?"

Comment: You could pickle the output from the first stage and then provide a command-line parameter to say "load the output from the first stage". https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm has its own Python Interactive Mode, Python Console, that allows you to run & debug python code in cells (as is done in iPython notebooks, with added debugging functionalities)

Press Ctrl + Shift + a, type Python Console, then press Enter.